# What's this insect on my eggplant?

Tags: insects, eggplant

I took my eggplant inside for the winter, and it's starting to flower again. But I've noticed a variety of insects on it. I see webs so assume that there are spiders around, I see aphids, and psyllids as well with their characteristic crystals deposited on the leaves.

This guy, about 5 mm long, is one I don't recognise. It has about 6 segments, and some fluffy hair on its tail.

What is it?

[image: Insect]

[image: Ventral view of insect]

I don't know how they survive since I sprayed heavily with pyrethrum yesterday.

Comment: Could it be a ladybird larva?

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know better, and as Aphids were a common pest on my eggplants, I'd suggest this is an aphid.  The picture looks quite similar to the one in Wikipedia for [Aphis pomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphis_pomi).

Speculating wildly, maybe the pyrethrum is not effective against this type of aphid, or maybe it has to do with [where the pyrethrum was manufactured from](http://www.cabdirect.org/abstracts/19310501975.html;jsessionid=C79FD52AE4335580B0FAC4A9E9713C75).

My wifes formula was water infused overnight with finely cut garlic + some soap, sprayed on the leaves as a spot treatment.  I do note that this was for a different type of aphid.

Comment: I don't think it's an aphid .. it's about 2-3x the size of any aphids I've ever seen, and it lacks the globular body.  It's closer in size to a ladybird. I left it alone so far, but perhaps I need to find it again, and send it packing!  But I was hoping it might be predating on the other bugs :(